# Swiper not switching slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I'm using [Swiper](https://idangero.us/swiper/) on a page I'm building for an artist, and I'm not good with Javascript. I'm loading the Swiper JavaScript files from the CDN at:

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.x.x/js/swiper.min.js

The site is being built locally, so it's not online for me to link to. I'm using a minimized jQuery.

After sorting out a few undefined function errors, I got the first slide showing on the page, along with the navigation arrows. However, the arrows don't actually do anything, and the slides aren't sliding at all, automatically or with the navigation arrows.

I followed the "[Getting Started with Swiper](https://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/)" guide on the Swiper site.

I've searched Google, the Swiper forums and Stack Overflow, but haven't found anything that's been helpful. I had issues with MIME types, solved those. But I haven't found anyone having a problem with the slides not switching out, so I suspect the problem is that I'm not good with JavaScript.

One issue I had was that I couldn't use the jQuery placeholder (`$`), I had to use the `jQuery` instead of `$` to get the slider to display at all.

What I'm expecting is that the images will slide automatically and with the navigation arrows. What happens is that the first image displays and doesn't change, even with the arrows.

```js
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  // Optional parameters
  direction: 'vertical',
  loop: true,

  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },

  // And if we need scrollbar
  scrollbar: {
    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">4</div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some minor issues:

1. The container needs the class "swiper-container".
   (Either that or the swiper selector should be `#content`.)
2. The buttons should be outside the wrapper.
   In your case, the [layout](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#layout) would be like:

```html
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

3. The "direction" was set to "vertical".
   I'm not sure of your exact application, but I've changed it to "horizontal" for this demo.

```js
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {

  // Optional parameters
  direction: 'horizontal',
  loop: true,

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  }

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/170/?1" alt=""></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/170/?2" alt=""></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/170/?3" alt=""></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/170/?4" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
```